# Loading an image from a MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a question about loading an image from a MySQL database.

I have my database set up named 'demo' with one table 'contacts'. This has the 4 columns 'id', 'name', 'email' and 'image'. I can insert images with a HTML page I created. I also can achieve all my information with another HTML page I created, but the inserted BLOB images won't pop up, instead I see some huge bunch of characters (seems to besome encoding/decoding problem).

Heres the php-script that should get the data:

```
<?php

/*db information*/
$localhost="localhost";
$username="riko";
$password="QdTkCd12!";
$database="demo";

/*connect to database*/
mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

/*prepare query*/
$query="SELECT * FROM contacts";
/*execute query*/
$result=mysql_query($query);
/*Number of rows delivered*/
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
/*Closing connection*/
mysql_close();


?>
<!-- Create a table to hold the data -->
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
  </tr>
<?php

//Iterating over all rows in our table
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {


//Get the first name, last name, mail and the image from the result
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"last");
$email=mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
$data =mysql_result($result,$i,"image");
?>

<tr>

**HERE I WANT TO ECHO THE IMAGE INTO MY TABLE BUT I ONLY GET A BUNCH OF CHARACTERS**

<td><img src="<?php echo $data ?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $first." ".$last; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:<? echo $email; ?>">E-Mail</a>
</tr>

<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me where my fault is? This is the php-script where I insert the images:

```
<?php
$localhost="localhost";
$username="riko";
$password="QdTkCd12!";
$database="demo";

$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];


mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

// Make sure the user actually
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

// Temporary file name stored on the server
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

// Read the file
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);

$query = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('','$first','$last','$email', '$data')";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
}

header("Location: connect.php");
die();
?>
```

I really don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to store image blob data in MySQL like you are doing.  99 times out of 100 when I see someone thinking about doing this, it doesn't really make sense. I would suggest just storing a URL/path reference in the DB. I see nothing in your code that would make me think you have any reason to store the image in the DB.

Comment: There are valid reasons to want this (not many, but still). Let's assume he has a valid reason, and answer his question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answers. I googled a bit and I think I understand why it is way better to store those images in the filesystem. Can anyone of you maybe tell me where I can find a good tutorial to this? I am running Xampp on my PC and have no real server, so it would be nice to have some introduction but I can only find BLOB tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prefix the value in the src attribute with content information:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $data . '" />';
```

Make sure the database blob field contains base64 encoded data.

Comment: I tried this after adding 
`$data=base64_encode($data);`
to my insert-script but it still shows nothing.